# macro to enter data in first row of excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have column names AA, BB, CC, DD, EE which are need to be entered in A1, B1, C1, D1, E1.

A macro would be helpful since i manually type the column name in the mentioned regularly.

Thanks and Regards,
Pandya Raj

Comment: Turn on the Macro Recorder and enter the values. Turn off the Macro Recorder and look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub setup()
    [A1] = "AA"
    [B1] = "BB"
    [C1] = "CC"
    [D1] = "DD"
    [E1] = "EE"
End Sub
```